# java script switch beetween audios with dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I got this code and I dont understand why its dont working
Jquery

> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> $('#selection').on('change', function() {
>     change($(this).val());
>    });
>
> });

javascript

```
function change(sourceUrl) {
        var audio = document.getElementById("player");
        var source = document.getElementById("mp3_src");

        audio.pause();

        if (sourceUrl) {
            source.src = sourceUrl;
            audio.load();
            audio.play();
        }
    }
```

html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="selection">Listen:</label>
<select id="selection">
  <option value="">- Select track -</option>
  <option value="About/Heathens-Stressed%20Out%20-MASHUP-%20Twenty%20One%20Pilots.mp3">song2</option>
  <option value="About/Twenty%20One%20Pilots%20-%20Stressed%20Out%20X%20Heathens%20(5Evan%20Mashup).mp3">song1</option>
</select>
<br/>
<audio id="player" controls="controls">
  <source id="mp3_src" src="/teachings/2011_01_09_Cut.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

[image: and this is what i get from the code]

if you look in the  picture its looks like the function is not loading/working can someone help me to fix it
i think the problem is that the function dont recevie anything from the dropdown list but i coudnt figure it out whats wrong and why its dont receive anything from the  dropdown

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. First, javascript is not java, read the tag description before using a tag. Then, don't post code as an image. Copy and paste it inside the question itself.

Comment: don't post pictures, post code where the problem might and what is the expected result and the problem itself.

Comment: ok i posted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code itself is working, just put it after you include jQuery, not before that. For better user experience and also to avoid such problems, always include all the libraries first, and then your JavaScript, just before you close the body tag.